# Using destructuring and renaming with import

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm currently building a bot for `Slack` using the [`node-slack-sdk`](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk). In their examples they got the following line:

```
var CLIENT_EVENTS = require('@slack/client').CLIENT_EVENTS;
```

The `CLIENT_EVENTS` is then used as follow:

```
rtm.on(CLIENT_EVENTS.RTM.AUTHENTICATED, function handleRTMAuthenticated() {
  console.log('RTM client authenticated!');
});
```

I've changed the `require` in order to use destructuring to directly get the `CLIENT_EVENTS.RTM` object that I renamed `RTM_CLIENT_EVENTS`.

```
const {
  CLIENT_EVENTS: { RTM: RTM_CLIENT_EVENTS },
} = require('@slack/client');
```

Now, I wanted to change the `require` to an `import`:

```
import {
  CLIENT_EVENTS: { RTM: RTM_CLIENT_EVENTS },
}  from '@slack/client';
```

But I got the following error:

> ES2015 named imports do not destructure. Use another statement for destructuring after the import

Any idea why they don't destructure?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`import` has [strict syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Syntax) that only mimics shallow destructuring syntax but is supposed to be statically analyzed. So does `export`, it mimics object literal syntax.

As the error suggests, the proper way to do this is

```
import { CLIENT_EVENTS }  from '@slack/client';

const { RTM: RTM_CLIENT_EVENTS } = CLIENT_EVENTS;
```

Comment: You're welcome. Strict syntax allows IDEs and linters to accurately figure out modules imports and exports, which wasn't possible with loose CommonJS modules.

Comment: It's important to note that destructuring is allowed and even renaming via: `import { exportName as newName } from 'some/lib'`. It just does not seem that nested destructuring is allowed. It's also important to note that you cannot rename as you normally would have to use `as` instead of `:`. Thanks for the link to strict syntax as well.

Answer (score 14):

The `import` statement in javascript does not natively support the destructuring syntax.
But you can rename the imports in the following ways:

```js
import {RTM_CLIENT_EVENTS as RTM} from '@slack/client'
```

Here the `RTM_CLIENT_EVENTS` propery will be imported and renamed to `RTM` using the `as` keyword.